# awk - ternary conditional expression not working

Tags: awk

**Input (sample)**

```
=== account ===
title,altTitle,platform,url,
title,altTitle,platform,url,
title,altTitle,platform,url,
title,altTitle,platform,url,
title,altTitle,platform,url,
```

`__collate-by-account.awk`

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
#
# Group together lines (records) by account name

BEGIN { FS = ":" }

### generate headers ###
{s = $1}
{if (s != p)
  print "\n\n=== ", s " ==="
}
{p = s}

### process records ###
# print field $2 to last field
{for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
#   {if (i!=NF) printf $i":"; else printf $i}
    { i != NF ? printf $i":" : printf $i }
}
{printf "\n"}
```

This part works as intended:
`{if (i!=NF) printf $i":"; else printf $i}`

Why doesn't this work:
`{ i != NF ? printf $i":" : printf $i }`

Getting the following errors:

```
awk: scripts/utils/metadata/__collate-by-account.awk:18:        { i != NF ? printf $i":" : printf $i }
awk: scripts/utils/metadata/__collate-by-account.awk:18:                    ^ syntax error
awk: scripts/utils/metadata/__collate-by-account.awk:18:        { i != NF ? printf $i":" : printf $i }
awk: scripts/utils/metadata/__collate-by-account.awk:18:                                 ^ syntax error
```

Comment: Parenthesis doesn't fix it: `{ (i != NF) ? printf $i":" : printf $i }`

Comment: The `printf` can't be inside the ternary operator, ie. use `printf "%s%s",$i,(i!=NF?":":"")`

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed now.. however I got another issue now with each record (line) being printed n amount of times where n depends on how many separators are present, so it's a semantic error with the loop, I'll investigate it :D

Comment: Would you mind explaining `%s%s` in the code snippet you posted? I'm also reading up on printf since I'm not too familiar with it.. Feel free to post an answer, if not I'll post one myself and credit you.

Comment: nvm it makes sense now that I read up a bit on it, they're placeholders for the strings that get passed in, the first one simply being `$i`, the second being `":"` if `i!=NF` else `""`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, thanks to [@James Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4162356/james-brown):

```
### process records ###
# print field $2 to last field
{for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
    { printf "%s%s",$i,(i!=NF?":":"") }
}
{printf "\n"}
```

Explaination:

- First off, note that `printf` can't be inside the ternary operator, neither the conditional expression to be evaluated (for obvious reasons) nor the resulting if-else expressions that will be executed after evaluation.
- `printf` formats and prints the results
- `%s%s` format specifiers, outputs or substitutes the next 2 arguments as strings:

  - https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Format-Modifiers.html
  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string
- `$i` simply output the field that's being looped over, see the above for-loop
- `(i!=NF?":":"")`

  - output `":"` if `i` is not equal to `NF`,
  - otherwise output empty string `""`

Comment: The idiomatic way to write that code is `'BEGIN{OFS=":"} {for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS) }'`.

Comment: Thank you for the example, it's useful to know the most concise, proper and idiomatic way to solve. If you'd like to write it into an answer with explanations I'll consider marking it as the approved answer.

Comment: If you add concise, testable sample input and expected output to your question then I'll take a look. I (and I suspect many others) haven't read the question yet since that's currently missing so idk if the answer you have is the best one or not.